# Pandas - check to see if all elements in a list are in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 3 columns - 'sport' 'age' 'name'

I have a list with different sports in, declared like this:

```
sports = ['tennis','cricket','swimming']
```

I want to check to see if all 3 of the sports are in the sport column. Currently, i have this:

```
if (df['sport']!=sport).any():
    print('no, the sports arent in the column')
```

So if all the sports in the list arent in the column I want to print no. The issue with my current code is that the sport column has many more elements than the sport list so gives me an error.

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `isin(sports).all()`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
sports = ['tennis','cricket','swimming']
df = pd.DataFrame({'sport': ['tennis','cricket','swimming']})
print(df["sport"].isin(sports).all())
```

Comment: I need to check if it is not in. Could i replace isin with notin

Comment: `print(~df["sport"].isin(sports).all())` ?

Comment: @HarryMaguire - What is expected output of `df = pd.DataFrame({'sport': ['tennis','cricket','swimming', 'another']})` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set.intersection`:

```
if not set(df['sport']).intersection(set(sports)):
    print('no, the sports arent in the column')
```

More efficiently, you can use `set.issubset`:

```
if not set(sports).issubset(set(df['sport'])):
    print('no, the sports arent in the column')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe need compare `set`s:

```
sports = ['tennis','cricket','swimming']
df = pd.DataFrame({'sport': ['tennis','cricket']})
print (df)
     sport
0   tennis
1  cricket

print(set(df['sport']) >= set(sports))
False

df = pd.DataFrame({'sport': ['tennis','cricket','swimming']})
print (df)
      sport
0    tennis
1   cricket
2  swimming

print(set(df['sport']) >= set(sports))
True

df = pd.DataFrame({'sport': ['tennis','cricket','swimming', 'another']})
print (df)
      sport
0    tennis
1   cricket
2  swimming
3   another

print(set(df['sport']) >= set(sports))
True
```